# Tensorflow: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, tensorflow

What's going on here?

The code:

```
def text_model(text, memory):
    import tensorflow as tf

    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

    # Text parsing.
    lastLayer = tf.convert_to_tensor([text, memory])
    for i in range(0, 200):
        thinking = tf.layers.dense(inputs = lastLayer, units = pow(10, 9), activation = tf.nn.relu)

        lastLayer = thinking, [32000, -1]
    response = tf.layers.dense(inputs = lastLayer, units = pow(10, 4), activation = tf.nn.relu)
    memory = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([lastLayer, response]), [-1])

    return [response, memory]

textList = text_model([1], [1])

print(textList)
```

The error report:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Other people who get the same error seem to get it in completely different contexts. Why is this error happening in this context and how can I fix it?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line sets `lastLayer` equal to a tuple:

```
lastLayer = thinking, [32000, -1]
```

When the `for` loop executes a second time, it will try to access `lastLayer` as a tensor, but you've converted it to a tuple. So you get the error.